# Intermittent instances of duplicate participant rows created - is this a MySQL issue?

Tags: mysql, registration

CiviCRM 4.4 install that has been running for ~ 2 years now, no update to code - in the past week I have seen 3 instances of duplicated participant rows (same contact_id, same event_id, fee, but register timestamp shows difference of 7 minutes to 1 hour).  The participant_id is different of course. Has anyone seen this or have suggestions how to debug this - MySQL server is hosted so I cannot get logs.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar and it has always been traced to the user submitting the (in our case) membership form twice.

For some reason the final "Your membership has now been created" (or whatever it says) message has not been displayed, so they think it has failed and submit again.  Worse still they may get  "We cannot provide that at this time", which they interpret to mean the transaction has failed when really I thnk it is a timeout message for displaying that final "Done" message.

They should have received a confirmation email, but they have given the wrong adress, or it is caught up in a spam filter or delayed in transmission or ?

Why three times in one week? Perhaps there has been a heavier-than-usual load on the shared server leading to time-outs for that final message.

Comment: Hi JoAnne - I don't know why now (3 x in short succession). I do know though that all 3 received confirmation emails - twice - so I am inclined to think it is a session problem rather than MySQL. I know that the event reg. 'thank you' page is supposed to kill the session at the end, and it is possble that the server load was heavy (it's shared but the client doesn't want to deal w/a VPS..) Thank you for answering!